# Ubuntu 23.10 - Unable to enable proposed

Tags: apt, updates

I am unable to enable proposed for in ubuntu 23.10.
I followed https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed and enabled pre-released updates (mantic-proposed) in Software & Updates

When I run `sudo apt update` I can see the added repository

> > Hit:13 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-proposed InRelease

When I run `sudo apt upgrade -s` I don't get any proposed packages.

Afterwards I also added a preferences.d pref file in /etc/apt/preferences.d/proposed-updates.pref because I thought maybe apt blocks proposed updates for all packages.

```
# Configure apt to allow selective installs of packages from proposed
Package: lcov
Pin: release a=mantic-proposed
Pin-Priority: 400
```

But after running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -s` again I still don't get any proposed packages.

I am sure I am doing something wrong, who can help me out?

PS: as you might already have seen, I am trying to pull [latest fix for lcov](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lcov/+bug/2029924). If I do something wrong with pinning the lcov package then please tell me how I should do this instead.

Comment: I would urge you not to enable proposed. https://popey.com/blog/2021/02/dont-use-proposed/

Comment: Which specific packages are you trying to upgrade to the proposed version? Perhaps there are currently none. Please [edit] with `apt-cache policy my_package_name` once you identify the specific package you would like to upgrade

Comment: @popey wouldn't it be "safe" enough if I pin only the lcov for proposed with the .pref file? Alternatively I could spin up a docker container and test if lcov is working with this fix. I need lcov for unit test coverage and it's currently broken in ubuntu 23.10

Comment: @user535733, I pinned the lcov package as I showed in the question. I never used the proposed repo before, so maybe I misunderstand the "pinning" part.

Comment: Check this `apt -s install -t mantic-proposed lcov`

Answer (score 2):

Your output shows that there was no `lconv` package in the `-proposed` pocket when you last ran `apt update`.

Try `apt update` again, because it's there now:

```
$ rmadison lcov
 [...]
 lcov | 1.15-1         | jammy/universe           | source, all
 lcov | 2.0-1          | mantic/universe          | source, all
 lcov | 2.0-1ubuntu0.1 | mantic-proposed/universe | source, all
 lcov | 2.0-4ubuntu1   | noble/universe           | source, all
```

Comment: Mind telling me what `rmadison` is? I can't seem to find that package on ubuntu either

Comment: @bas `sudo apt install devscripts` for `rmadison`. AskUbuntu answerers use it because it's faster than packages.ubuntu.com

Comment: Ah. nevermind that. google knew the answer too... devscripts_2.23.6_all

Comment: When reading this output, would you expect that this source should find the lcov package in proposed?

deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ mantic-proposed multiverse universe restricted main

I assume it doesn't matter that I am using Dutch mirrors right?
Because when I install lcov, it still picks the one from the official repos and not the proposed ones..

Comment: I would expect, on a properly-working system using properly-working mirrors, the new package to show in `apt policy lcov` within 24 hours of appearing in rmadison. It takes time for mirrors to sync.

Answer (score 1):

As popey said, it's unwise to enable proposed. You said your actual goal is "to pull latest fix for lcov", so let's do only that:

1. Download the deb from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lcov/2.0-1ubuntu0.1/+build/27753680
2. `sudo dpkg -i filename.deb`

While manually installing debs is bad, it is better in this situation because proposed is worse. As long as you made sure it's from the official Launchpad with the correct package, Ubuntu release, and architecture, you can be sure that it is safer for not breaking the rest of your system and for ensuring it will keep updating once a newer normal version is released.

Comment: Did this work btw. Still stubern enough to figure out why I can't achieve the same using -proposed :). Thx for this already! (unfortunately lcov still seems to be broken though...)

Comment: If "lcov still seems to be broken", then that's why that version is still in proposed and the Ubuntu developers haven't decided to release it to updates